# A server side validation problem at razor page

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, validation, razor-pages

Below is a small part of my data insert form.
My problem is;
The first form object is for the name of the Class room. The field is required and I wanna validate it at server side . In normal it works for sure. But since the next form object is an dropdown menu which get filled from a table of my database, the validation doesn't work. When i post it with empty class room field I get a error.
Normaly it is expected that the server side validation work and stop the posting action right ?
But it doesn't.
What do I miss here ? Thank you.

PS: The teacher field in DB is nullable and when i type something in the class room textbox the form works w/o any problem.

```
...
...
<div class="col-8 form-floating p-2">
    <input type="text" asp-for="AddClassRoom.Class" class="form-control" />
    <label asp-for="AddClassRoom.Class"></label>
    <span asp-validation-for="AddClassRoom.Class" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-8 form-floating p-2">
    <select class="form-select" asp-for="AddClassRoom.Teacher" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.ApplicationUser.OrderBy(x => x.NameSurname).ToList(),"Id","NameSurname"))">
    <option value="">select...</option>
    </select>
    <label asp-for="AddClassRoom.Teacher"></label>
<span asp-validation-for="AddClassRoom.Teacher" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
...
...
```

Comment: What's the error? How are you doing SS validation?

Comment: You can try to remove `<option value="">select...</option>`,or you can use `ModelState.IsValid` before adding data to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to you comment:

> Error is; null parameter(source). Well this is ok, i know it. But there must be a simple way to validate an insert form who has an Database driven content dropdown menu. Post and don't get null after server side validation.

It seems that the dropdown values are not populated after posting the form. Since you have the dropdown values are coming from DB, you need to get its items again from DB after posting the form, so the razor page can fill it again.

More support can be provided if you share your backend code.

#### [Sample]

Here is a basic sample depending on your code;

```html
<select class="form-select" asp-for="AddClassRoom.Teacher" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.ApplicationUser.OrderBy(x => x.NameSurname).ToList(),"Id","NameSurname"))">
    <option value="">select...</option>
    </select>
```

Backend:

```cs
public ActionResult OnGet() {
    // ...

    ApplicationUsers = GetApplicationUsersFromDb();

    Return Page();
}

public ActionResult OnPost() {
    // ...

    ApplicationUsers = GetApplicationUsersFromDb();

    Return Page();
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly as you said Ziya kardeş :) After post and server side validation the dropdown menus don't get filled/populated again. But I just wonder how to rid over this. Because on each insert form with a DB driven dropdown menu this will happen agin.

Comment: @CumhurK. kardeş :) just put the logic of populating the dropdown values from db inside the post method and before the return to view. This way the dropdown will get its values after post.

Comment: I didn't understood exactly how to do what you're talking about. A small concrete example maybe?

Comment: I added a sample code for your reference...

Comment: Omg lol... I feel ashamed now. Thank you for reminding me that :)